# gparted and partition ubuntu server

Tags: virtualbox, partition, ubuntu-server

I want to add the unallocated space to my partition /dev/sda1 but Gparted seems to prevent this
how to fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: Seems to prevent? Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: I want to add unallocated space to /dev/sda1

Comment: What I'm asking is that you elaborate on how Gparted is preventing it. Are you getting some sort of error message? Are you just unfamiliar with the software?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by delteting /dev/sda5 (it has no data already) then a recreate it in the end of partion